# getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay() is not working

Tags: android

I am using this code and the getWindowManager().getDeafulltDisplay portion showing an error. i am using Activity . this is a code for pop up window. if anyone have a better code for pop up window code please provide. actually getwindow function is not working

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
   import android.view.WindowManager;


 public class PopActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_popupd);
  }



     DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     *getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);* 
     int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
     int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
     getWindow().setLayout((int))(width*,8)(int)(height*.7));

  }
```

Comment: Include the error.

Comment: invalid method declaration; return type required. 
 actually the star marked line (*-----*) is not working . it red by the way .

Comment: use getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics); hope it will work

Comment: no it's not working